# Synchronize clock between DOS and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sync

I have problem with getting time to synchronize between a PC MS-DOS 6.22 and Microsoft Network Client 3.0 and a Windows 7 Ultimate box. This previously worked between the DOS PC and an XP machine.

I follow the instructions in [this discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/643239/lan-connection-dos-to-windows-7) and successfully connected to my other computers with Windows 7, but I cannot synchronize the clock on the DOS computer.

I used `net time \\Windows7 /set /yes`, but it gives me `"error 1 an internal error occurred"`.

Comment: If you do a `net /?` on the DOS machine, does it show TIME as a valid Net command?

Comment: the problem is i can synchronized dos computer with windowsXP computer, bute with windows 7 can't

Comment: That'd be worth editing into your question to mention it. ;)

Comment: If you type `w32tm /query /status` from the command-line of your Win7 computer, what does it say under `Stratum:`?

Comment: Leap Indicator: 3(last minute has 61 seconds)
Stratum: 0 (unspecified)
Precision: -6 (15.625ms per tick)
Root Delay: 0.0000000s
Root Dispersion: 0.0000000s
ReferenceId: 0x00000000 (unspecified)
Last Successful Sync Time: unspecified
Source: Local CMOS Clock
Poll Interval: 10 (1024s)

Comment: @Nasko Like i mentioned in that discussion... do you get the same error when you do `NET VIEW \\Windows7` or `NET VIEW \\IP_ADDRES_OF_Windows7`? And can you connect with the Windows7 **without** an error (`NET USE P: \\Windows7\SHARE`)?

Comment: @Nasko FYI: I dusted off my old laptop and tried it again. I needed to add the TCP protocol but now i get `Error 50: This request is not supported by the network` when i try to do a `NET VIEW \\Windows7`. I get the same with `NET TIME \\Windows7 /SET`. However `NET USE P: \\Windows7\SHARE` still works perfectly and i browse the new created drive-letter. I remember reading somewhere the newer Windows-versions are much more restricted (see my remark about the change with `gpedit.msc` i had to do to get it working) and maybe not all functions work (or i missed an option still needing to be set).

Comment: when i type NET VIEW \\Windows7 give me error 1, when use NET VIEW \\ip-Windows7 i get error 53 The computer name specified in the network path cannot be located. But the ip address of Windows7 is correct. I connect to Windows7 share folder and have full rights on the folder.

Comment: i can see files on share folder in Windows7, i make the same user and password on both machines, after this i connect to windows7, but time synch give me error 1 an internal error occured

Answer (score 0):

(possible solution for time-sync in DOS at the bottom)

It's the same with two DOS-machine of mine. One gives error 50 (unsupported) and the other gives error 1 (like yours). It think the problem is with the protocol used by `NET` to request the time (and also the 'NET VIEW' command). If i take a quick look at WireShark on the Windows 7 machine i can see the following traffic (image below):

DOS-machine is 192.168.1.23 and Windows 7 machine is 192.168.1.33
Command used on DOS is `NET TIME \\XPS8500`

[image]

You can see that the DOS-machine (192.168.1.23) requests `NetRemoteTOD` via the `LANMAN`-protocol. Which isn't supported anymore by Windows 7 (as you can see by the answer back).

When i do the same from a Windows XP-machine (192.168.1.67) i get:

[image]

You can see Windows XP uses the `SRVSVC`-protocol.

It's the same with the `NET VIEW` command. From DOS `NET` it uses the `LANMAN`-protocol to request a `NetShareEnum` while from Windows XP it uses `SRVSVC` to request a `NetShareEnumAll`.
Unfortunately we can't use the `NET.EXE` from Windows XP or '98 in DOS.

Luckily the `NET USE`-command only uses the `SMB`-protocol so access to the shares still work.
Just the `NET VIEW` and `NET TIME` commands are defect.

---

There is another solution if you only want to synchronize the time.
You can look at [SNTPC - A Simple Network Time Protocol Client for MS-DOS](http://www.josh.com/SNTPC/). I haven't tried it because it would need another protocol ([FTP's PC/TCP-protocol](ftp://ftp.hs-merseburg.de/pub/windows3x/winsock/ftpsoft/pctcp.html)) loaded (another memory hog) but it should do the job for syncing with any NTP-server on the internet. I'm not even sure you can get the PC/TCP-protocol anymore (now FTP is out of business) and you would probably need [QEMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMM) or [386MAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/386MAX) to maximize lower memory or else you would have little memory to run any programs.

Another possible solution is [mTCP SNTP](http://www.brutman.com/mTCP/mTCP_Sntp.html). (this one you *can* actually get your hands on)

And [another one](http://www.2net.co.uk/2time.html) (non-free).

Comment: i have other question, it is possible to get time from network server like time.windows.com ?

Comment: Yes, with the last 3 possible solutions you should be able to get the time from a NTP-server (which `time.windows.com` is). If it doesn't work with the host name you could try it with the corresponding ip-address. I would recommend you start with [mTCP SNTP](http://www.brutman.com/mTCP/mTCP_Sntp.html). From what i could see you could download all the necessary drivers. First you need the packet driver for your network card. Second connect with `dhcp`-command to a dhcp-server and last use the `sntp` command to get the time from either time.windows.com or ip or any other NTP-server.